# Which technique will be better to store IOS app data and run app in offline mode??Documents directory or cache directory or temprary directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi recently my app has been rejected by APPLE, they says

> We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.
>   In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your app stores 3.11 MB. To check how much data your app is storing:
>   - Install and launch your app
>   - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
>   - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
>   - Check your app's storage
>   The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc., should be backed up by iCloud.
>   Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the/tmp directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location when the user exits the app.
>   Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.
>   For more information, please see Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?.
>   It is necessary to revise your app to meet the requirements of the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. 
>   For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult withApple Developer Technical Support. Please be sure to:
>   - include the complete details of your rejection issues
>   - prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.
>   For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application Crash Reports.
>   If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/TestingWorkflow with Xcode's Archive feature".

What should i do now??Need Help

Comment: You can store datas in Cache directory which can reproduced even if they deleted. Datas stored in Cache directory will not be backed up by iCloud. We also experienced a rejection before for the same reason. All we did is to move all the datas to Cache directory.

Comment: And how long does cache directory persist data??

Comment: NSCachesDirectory can be deleted in cases of low memory. If you do not want the files be deleted even in low memory then save it under Document Directory and don't forget to use the "do not back up" attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also face the same issue. To resolve this issue you should do some code so that your DocumentDirectory should not sync with iCould. For that you have to set one flat to your DocumentDirectory which is known as **Don't BackUp**.

To achieve that use [code provided by the Apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html).

To know more then you can refere [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891271/dont-backup-to-icloud-but-still-rejected).

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!

Comment: What if i store data in Cache directory? Will it then also backed up to the iCloud??

Comment: Yes you can. But the best way is Mark your DocumentDirectory as Don't Back up

Comment: If you store in Cache, it will not be back up to iCloud. But, you have to manage the possibility that the cache is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what Apple is telling you that only documents that the user expressly creates and wants to save are what should be stored in iCloud.

Otherwise, you can save the files your app creates to the "Documents" directory (if you want it to persist between launches) or the Temporary folder (if you don't care what happens to the files between the device being powered up and down).

And in connection with Yashesh's answer (+1 to him!), make certain that iCloud is turned off by going to the Target (app) settings and turning the "iCloud" checkbox to ***off***, like this:

[image: Turn Off iCloud]

Comment: currently i'm saving all my data in cache directory, is that a safe technique considering above rejection by APPLE??

Comment: what are you saving in the iCloud directory, then?  the cache files?

Comment: I haven't integrated iCloud yet, what i'm doing is that, i'm saving all the image to the applications documents directory and some plist files too, so that when internet is not available i can retrieve older data from documents directory and now i'm approaching towards cache directory, so should i do that or better approach will be to integrate iCloud? I never did that actually

Comment: Are you saying that if the iCloud entitlement is not turned on, then it is not necessary to use the [don't back up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10892882/340947) flag on the files placed in Documents?